# Extract machine name from connection string

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ado.net, connection-string

Does someone knows how to extract machine name from SQL connection string?
For example for following connection strings, when ran app/script on the machine "ighost", which has ip address 190.190.200.100:

```
"Server=ighost;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
"Server=(local);Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
"Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
"Server=190.190.200.100,1433;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

I would like to get the as the result, just machine name:

```
ighost
```

This i not a duplicate of question above since I'm not asking how to parse connection string, but how to find server machine name even if connection string server property contains such value as (local), localhost, ipaddress, dot.

Comment: Do ighost, (local), .\SqlExpress, and 190.190.200.100,1433 refer to the same server?

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those connection strings refer to the same server, the only way for reliably find out the machine name is to connect to the server and run the following command:

```
select @@SERVERNAME
```

Sample code:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select @@SERVERNAME", cn))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem of this approach for me is that the user needs to have access to the database. For example if windows authentication is used and user under which I ran script/exe doesn't have permissions to the db, this will not work. I need to resolve server name without connecting to the server.

Comment: If the user does not have access to the db, why do you need to verify the connection string in the first place?

Comment: 1. I don't need to verify connection strings, I need to get machine name from connection string.
2. My script will ran under NT System account or some other account and will get connection strings from different sources. The actual applications, which use this connection strings may run under different accounts

Comment: Thanks, tried to find more, but this looks really like the only reliable way.